# Serial ports grayed out when Arduino plugged in (MS Surface Pro X, Windows 10 Pro 21H2). How do I get Arduino IDE to recognize them?

Tags: arduino-ide

I am helping a Windows user program an Arduino application. The computer is a Surface Pro X running Windows 10 Pro 21H2. It only has USB-C ports (which cannot be used to power or program Arduinos) so he's using [this USB-C hub](https://www.mokinglobal.com/product/usb-c-hub-5-in-1-21.html) and a USB-type A to USB-C cable to program it. The Arduino is a Sparkfun Artemis Redboard (Cortex M4).

When he connects the Arduino to the Surface Pro, the Arduino powers up as normal, but no serial ports are visible in the Arduino IDE, and the serial port line remains grayed out.

By contrast, the same USB-C hub, cable, and Arduino can be programmed by a Mac. I run Linux and don't know anything about USB port access on either Mac or Windows, but I got the impression that manually installing drivers should not be necessary on either.

Any advice on how to get the Arduino IDE to recognize this as a serial port when plugged in to a Surface Pro?

Comment: A Mac is based on Unix/Linux.  I believe you can open a console on a Mac and type the Linux command lsusb to list the attached USB devices just like you do on a Linux box.  On the Win10 box ... I would consult the Sparkfun web site and discover if there is any special drivers that need to be installed to prompt Win10 to create a serial port.  Also, you may try to connect A USB device that you know will generate a serial port to test if the HUB you are using on the Sur/Pro/10 is actually working as expected.

Comment: Do you get the typical USB chime when you insert the device? Because if you don't, if it doesn't list at all in Device Manager, even temporarily, even as an unrecognized USB device, then the drivers are not a problem to worry about (yet anyway).  USB devices have to work well for the operating system in order to get USB device descriptor for it to even know what driver it should be trying to load.

Answer (score 2):

Consider running through [this Sparkfun Hookup Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/hookup-guide-for-the-sparkfun-redboard-artemis-nano/troubleshooting) for the [SparkFun RedBoard Artemis](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15444https://).  There is a section dealing with this problem:

> My Nano is not showing up as a COM port?!
> Most Artemis carrier boards use the CH340C IC which is not affected by
> this issue. This issue is only for the Nano that uses the much smaller
> CH340E.